# Return subClass

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

My question is quite easy, but I cannot figure out how to implement what I want.

I would like to implement a method which, depending of the given parameter, returns one subClass or another (I understand that I could have this behavior in some class to make the development more object oriented, but I'm still learning).

So I thought of this solution, but it does not compile.

```
public abstract class A(){
    //some code
}

public class B extends A(){
    //some code
}

public class c extends A(){
    //some code
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("input: "); 
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String input=console.nextLine();
    A myObject = getObject(input);

}

public static <? extends A> getObject(String input){
    if(input.indexOf("b") != -1){
        return new B();
    }
    if(input.indexOf("c") != -1){
        return new C();     
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: And what is the error? Please post the full compiler error.

Comment: Generics won't be useful here, they don't exist during program execution (when `input` is evaluated).

Comment: You haven't get a return type on your method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to remove the brackets (`()`) from your class definitions:

```
public abstract class A {
    //some code
}

public class B extends A {
    //some code
}

public class C extends A {
    //some code
}
```

Second, `getObject` should just return `A`:

```
public static A getObject(String input){
    if(input.indexOf("b") != -1){
        return new B();
    }
    if(input.indexOf("c") != -1){
        return new C();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, I don't see any need to use generics. Your method can simply return `A` :

```
public static A getObject(String input){
    if(input.indexOf("b") != -1){
        return new B();
    }
    if(input.indexOf("c") != -1){
        return new C();     
    }
    return null;
}
```